# Data in SharePoint Online is not showing in the column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, multiple-lines-of-text

**Problem:**

Data in SharePoint Online list is not showing in the column unless I double click on the row.

You can find a picture related to my problem attached below:

[image]

[image]

What's the best practice to use to solve the above problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add any [custom JSON formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) in your SharePoint list?

Comment: No, the problem was from the enhance rich text option in the column settings. Thank you for your fast reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: yes, I see you have enabled enhanced rich text in 2nd image. But it should show data in list view as well. It is working correctly in my list.

Comment: Looks like a new bug. @RobertoHajj. Did you try creating a support ticket with Microsoft?

Comment: Is this issue only with this list? Try to create a  new list to test.